# Why div's go further right than body?

Tags: html, css

Why `nav` and `.logo` go further right than `body`? There's the scroll right option and I don't want this. I've set `body` to be 100% right, I know this may have to do with margins of different elements, but my tests have been unsuccessful. Can someone help? Thanks

```css
html {
  width:100%;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}

.banner {
  background:green;
  width:100%;
  height:1000%;
  position:absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center fixed;
 z-index:-1;
}

.navigation {
  background:red;
  z-index:1;
  width:35%;
  left:55%;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
}

.navigation a {
  display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  margin:20px;
  font-size:120%;
}

.logo {
  width:60%;
  height:120px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  top:130px;
  left:130px;
  background:yellow;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center fixed;
}

.headline {

  position:relative;
  top:200px;
  left:10%;
  
}

.headlineBar {
  width:80px;
  height:3px;
  background-color:white;
}

.headline p {
  font-size:300%;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    
  </header>
  <div class="banner">
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <a href="#">SPEAKERS</a>
    <a href="#">SPONSOR</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="headlineBar"></div>
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing block elements to the right with relative positioning and the `left` property.

```
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    left: 55%;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    left: 130px;
}

.headline {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}
```

Keep in mind that [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) occupy the full available width of their parent (in this case, the `body`). So when you apply the positioning above, the elements (keeping their full width) shift right according to the value you have specified. This pushes them past the right border of the `body`, launching the horizontal scrollbar.

Remove those values and the scrollbar disappears.

If you want to move those boxes around the screen horizontally, give them a `width` or change their display property to `inline-block`.

Comment: As you develop your site, I suggest adding borders to each box (just for dev purposes). Then you can see exactly where things are going. As I mentioned in my answer, a defined width for each box should be useful to you, or try using `display: inline-block`, which will give you the versatility of a block element, but will wrap the box like an inline element.

Comment: thanks, @Michael_B! I deleted my comment as your last edit to your answer had answered my question. Indeed, adding `display:inline-block` fixes the issue. I always use a similar trick, by adding a `background` color. However, even without `display:inline-block` the area of the box was fine (not going further right than `body`), hence why I couldn't detect the problem. I had set a smaller `width` and used `left`, so all looked fine. But again, `inline-block` fixes the issue so happy time :) Thanks again,